# How to reload/refresh the content of div without clicking the button or ink in javascript/ jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How do i reload/refresh the div in a couple of seconds without refreshing the whole page and without clicking any button or link. The div below with id='div_graph' is the div i want to reload/refresh. Note: inside the dashboard.php contains query.

```
<div id="div_graph">
<?php
    include('folder/dashboard.php');
?>
</div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use `setInterval()` to run a function periodically, and it can use AJAX to get the new contents of the DIV.

Comment: use setTimeOut() and XHR request to load the div dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is too broad for this site. Broadly, to reload a single div you need some client side code (often javascript) to either trigger the update or send a request. You will have to have code on the server side to receive that request and generate the data (or the entire div) and send it back. You then need to have client side code to apply or update the div.

You question is close to, "how to I jquery ajax?"

There are lots of guides if you *search* for "**how to use jquery ajax with php**". Good luck.

Comment: i found a lot of way on how to reload a div but it won't works. But anyway thanks for sharing.

Comment: If you are using existing code it may be getting in the way of your understanding. Start with a blank HTML page and write the javascript to just update a div with the local time. Then create a new script and prototype the functionality that you need between the client and server.